# What is $\mathbb Q^3$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> What is $\mathbb Q^3$ ?

I have to find a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q^3$, but is $\mathbb Q^3=\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ ?

using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function

can I say that;

$\mathbb Q^3=\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\overset b\rightarrow\mathbb N^6\overset b\rightarrow\mathbb N$

but in the link the function $\pi$ goes from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, so it remains to show a one-to-one correspondance of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ (explicitly), how can one construct such a function ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ just means vectors of length $n$ whose entries are each in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If $b$ is a function with domain $\mathbb{Q}^3$ and range $\mathbb{N}^6$, then it cannot also have domain $\mathbb{N}^6$ and range $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @EricTressler  No, I mean that there is just a bijection

Comment: @ketum The natural map from $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}^2$ is the map $a/b \to (a,b)$, which you can use to go from $\mathbb{Q}^k \to \mathbb{N}^{2k}$. Of course, it's not naturally bijective, since $(a,0)$ has no preimage in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @EricTressler but what is the image of the negative rationals under that map ?

Comment: @keturn The positive integers have the same cardinatity as the integers (ie: there's a bijection), so by induction, the positive rationals have the same cardinality as all the rationals.

Comment: @ketum Thanks for pointing that out; I guess you would need to establish a rule of the form $a/b \to (2a,2b)$, $-(a/b) \to (2a+1, 2b+1)$, and stipulate that $a/b$ is reduced and $a,b > 0$. Then you still need to deal with the pairs $(x,0)$, which is why nobody does this explicitly.

Comment: @ketum you may be interested to learn that there is a sequence that contains every (positive) rational number exactly once, and that this particular sequence is generated by a simple recursive formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree

Answer (score 0):

The pairing function used twice gives us a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^3 = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. If you also have a bijection $f$ between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, then then you use $f \times f \times f$ combined with the former bijection.